# SQL How to do substraction based on my below case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to I set a column called `NEW_BAL`, result are from `strResponseTextNull` minus of the `MIGS_STATUS_Approved`:

```
SELECT  
    Convert(char(8), WebPayH_dtmRequest, 112)as MIGSPaymentRequestDate,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as strResponseTextNull,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strApproved like 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as MIGS_STATUS_Approved,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Transaction+was+blocked+by+the+Payment+Server+because+it+did+not+pass+all+risk+checks.' then 1 else 0 end) as RiskCheckNotPass,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'The+card+holder+was+not+authorised.+This+is+used+in+3-D+Secure+Authentication.' then 1 else 0 end) as ThreeDNotEnabled,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Expired+Card' then 1 else 0 end) as ExpiredCard,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Declined' then 1 else 0 end) as DeclinedByBank,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Insufficient+Funds' then 1 else 0 end) as InsufficientFunds,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Timed+Out' then 1 else 0 end) as TimerOut,

**-- SELECT strResponseTextNull - SUM MIGS_STATUS_Approved AS NEW_BAL**

    count(WebPayH_strResponseCode) AS TotalMIGSPaymentRequest
FROM 
    [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblWebPaymentHistory]
WHERE 
    WebPayH_dtmRequest >= '2015-05-07'
GROUP BY 
    Convert(char(8), WebPayH_dtmRequest, 112) 
ORDER BY 
    Convert(char(8), WebPayH_dtmRequest, 112)
```

Comment: Basically I want a new field call NEW_BAL, result are gathered from result strResponseTextNull substract  MIGS_STATUS_Approved

Comment: Put your query in a subquery, and then do the subtraction in the main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```sql
SELECT  
    Convert(char(8), WebPayH_dtmRequest, 112)as MIGSPaymentRequestDate,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as strResponseTextNull,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strApproved like 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as MIGS_STATUS_Approved,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Transaction+was+blocked+by+the+Payment+Server+because+it+did+not+pass+all+risk+checks.' then 1 else 0 end) as RiskCheckNotPass,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'The+card+holder+was+not+authorised.+This+is+used+in+3-D+Secure+Authentication.' then 1 else 0 end) as ThreeDNotEnabled,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Expired+Card' then 1 else 0 end) as ExpiredCard,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Declined' then 1 else 0 end) as DeclinedByBank,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Insufficient+Funds' then 1 else 0 end) as InsufficientFunds,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText like 'Timed+Out' then 1 else 0 end) as TimerOut,
    SUM(case when WebPayH_strResponseText IS NULL then 1 else 0 end)-SUM(case when WebPayH_strApproved like 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as NEW_BAL,
    count(WebPayH_strResponseCode) AS TotalMIGSPaymentRequest
FROM 
    [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblWebPaymentHistory]
WHERE 
    WebPayH_dtmRequest >= '2015-05-07'
GROUP BY 
    Convert(char(8), WebPayH_dtmRequest, 112) 
ORDER BY 
    Convert(char(8), WebPayH_dtmRequest, 112)
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, that is all I want!